# The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

"The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes"

I have got this error in MySQL when i am running a query which includes "contains" keyword. How to make a table support "SPATIAL indexes". The query is

select * from table where contains(column,"1")

Comment: Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mysql support spatial index only with *.myisam tables, i.e. the ISAM engine. Link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html

Comment: I created a Spatial Index on my table. Then changed the ENGINE to MYISAM with an Alter Table SQL. Then when I do EXPLAIN on my query I can still see that the Spatial index is unsed...

Comment: What about mariaDB?

Answer (score 8):

Mysql support for spatial indexes firstly added for tables with MyISAM engine. Support for InnoDB engine added as of version 5.7.5.

```
MyISAM: >= 5.0
InnoDB: >= 5.7.5
```