# Cannot set spatial index to geometry type - #1464

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, spatial, spatial-index

I use MySQL version 5.5.49. They type of the column is `geometry` and the engine of the table is InnoDB.

I try something like

```
ALTER TABLE geom ADD SPATIAL INDEX(field);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE geom ADD SPATIAL INDEX table (field);
```

or

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sp_index ON table(field);
```

and I get the error

> #1464 - The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes

Does this has to do with the engine of the table, the version of MySQL or am I missing something?

I read [The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379808/the-used-table-type-doesnt-support-spatial-indexes) that is the engine that causes the problem. Do I really have to change the engine? InnoDB is more suitable for my needs.

Comment: As far as mysql doc is concerned spatial index is supported in myIsam Engine.See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html

Comment: Then upgrade your MySQL to v5.7.5

Comment: @Bikash P Thank you. Do you know which version support spatial data in innoDB? Thanks

Comment: @Shadow version Does 5.7.5 support spatial data and indexes in innoDB?

Comment: @slevin have you read the document linked by Bikash in the 1st comment? Because this is described in the 1st sentence there...

Comment: @Shadow Thanks, I just noticed that.